# Overriding FB Auto Connect plugin function displayed in footer

Tags: plugins, facebook

I have FB Auto Login plugin installed and i have wrote my own custom javascript to handle logins. Now my question is how do i override the jfb_output_facebook_init function with my own function which echos "Hello World" for example?

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'jfb_output_facebook_init');
function jfb_output_facebook_init()
{
global $jfb_name, $jfb_version, $opt_jfb_app_id, $opt_jfb_api_key, $opt_jfb_valid;
if( !get_option($opt_jfb_valid) ) return;

$channelURL = plugins_url(dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__))) . "/facebook-platform/channel.html";
echo "\n<!-- $jfb_name Init v$jfb_version (NEW API) -->\n";
?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">//<!--
  window.fbAsyncInit = function()
  {
    FB.init({
        appId: '<?php echo get_option($opt_jfb_app_id); ?>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth:true, channelUrl: '<?php echo $channelURL; ?>' 
    });
    <?php do_action('wpfb_add_to_asyncinit'); ?>            
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/<?php echo apply_filters('wpfb_output_facebook_locale', 'en_US'); ?>/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
//--></script>

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply remove the old function using [`remove_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) hook, and add your own using [`add_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) hook.

**Example -**

```
remove_action('wp_footer', 'jfb_output_facebook_init');
add_action('wp_footer', 'your_function');
```

Comment: You sir, are a legend. Worked like a charm :)